Kenmore washer won't drain, multimeter found a continuity error
My 110.20722990 Kenmore washing machine was fine two weeks ago. Then a big thunderstorm hit, and it immediately stopped draining. The wash and agitate and fill and rinse cycles still worked just fine, and there were no strange mechanical noises... it just quietly stops when the drain cycle activates... so I figured it was probably an electrical problem.

Changing the temperature, spin speed, load size switches had no effect.
Trying other cycles (such as "permanent press") had no effect.
Opening/closing the lid had no effect. (Neither did holding the lid switch lever down with a screwdriver while the lid was open.)

I pulled out the timer and tested it for continuity with a multimeter based off the wiring diagram.

Sure enough, I found an error. First, I made sure to remove the timer right when it was stopped on the faulty drain cycle. Then, I tested every connection on the timer terminals. Every connection was correct, except one: According to the wiring diagram, the tan-blue circuit was supposed to be ON during the "drain hi" cycle, but the multimeter found that it was OFF.
So, naively, I replaced the timer. Same issue with the new timer: no draining, and no continuity on the tan-blue circuit.
Now I'm wondering: What switch do I test next? I'm not sure how to read the wiring diagram. (Or maybe a wire is bad?)
Thanks!

you've drawn two red squares, does the pump work correctly in the other timer switch positions?

does the low water level sensor work?
